# Remove single quotes in list of values in macro variable

Tags: sas

I have a project with multiple programs. Each program has a proc SQL statement which will use the same list of values for a condition in the WHERE clause; however, the column type of one database table needed is a character type while the column type of the other is numeric.

So I have a list of "Client ID" values I'd like to put into a macro variable as these IDs can change, and I would like to change them once in the variable instead of in multiple programs.

For example, I have this macro variable set up like so and it works in the proc SQL which queries the character column:
`%let CLNT_ID_STR = ('179966', '200829', '201104', '211828', '264138');`

Proc SQL part:
`...IN &CLNT_ID_STR.`

I would like to create another macro variable, say CLNT_ID_NUM, which takes the first variable (CLNT_ID_STR) but removes the quotes.

Desired output: `(179966, 200829, 201104, 211828, 264138)`

Proc SQL part: `...IN &CLNT_ID_NUM.`

I've tried using the `sysfunc`, `dequote` and `translate` functions but have not figured it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TRANSLATE doesn't seem to want to allow a null string as the replacement.

Below uses TRANSTRN, which has no problem translating single quote into null:

```
1    %let CLNT_ID_STR = ('179966', '200829', '201104', '211828', '264138');
2    %let want=%sysfunc(transtrn(&clnt_id_str,%str(%'),%str())) ;
3    %put &want ;
(179966, 200829, 201104, 211828, 264138)
```

It uses the macro quoting function %str() to mask the meaning of a single quote.

Comment: This met my needs. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Three other ways to remove single quotes are `COMPRESS`, `TRANSLATE` and `PRXCHANGE`

```
%let CLNT_ID_STR = ('179966', '200829', '201104', '211828', '264138');

%let id_list_1 = %sysfunc(compress (&CLNT_ID_STR, %str(%')));
%let id_list_2 = %sysfunc(translate(&CLNT_ID_STR, %str( ), %str(%')));
%let id_list_3 = %sysfunc(prxchange(%str(s/%'//), -1, &CLNT_ID_STR));

%put &=id_list_1;
%put &=id_list_2;
%put &=id_list_3;

----- LOG -----

ID_LIST_1=(179966, 200829, 201104, 211828, 264138)
ID_LIST_2=( 179966 ,  200829 ,  201104 ,  211828 ,  264138 )
ID_LIST_3=(179966, 200829, 201104, 211828, 264138)
```

It really doesn't matter that `TRANSLATE` replaces the `'` with a single blank ()  because the context for interpretation is numeric.